# Force implicit conversion to most general shared class?

Tags: r, list

Is there a function to force implicit conversion rules onto a heterogeneous list in order to convert it to an atomic vector of the most general shared class? For example, if I have `list("apple", 12, TRUE)`, how can I turn this into `c("apple", "12", "TRUE")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R's class hierarchy roughly is logical < factor < integer < numeric < character. So `unlist` whch coerces into character should help, then `list` again to get list format.

```
list(unlist(list("apple", 12, TRUE)))
# [[1]]
# [1] "apple" "12"    "TRUE"
```

If we have a nested list, we can create a `"relistable"` object which inherits from `"list"` and use `relist` after `unlist`:

```
l <- as.relistable(list("apple", list(12), TRUE))
relist(unlist(l))
# [[1]]
# [1] "apple"
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "12"
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "TRUE"
```

Comment: @user20650 Thanks for pointing out! Added to answer.